# Help undertanding why a change does not work in this case? ( cylinder)

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I´m trying to solve a problem that goes as follows:

Find the equation of the cylinder circumscribed to the sphere $$x^2+y^2+z^2-2x+4y+2z-3=0$$ with generatrix parallel to the line:
$$x=2t-7, y=-t+7, z=-2t+5.$$

I´ve tried using the identity for a circular cylinder  with axis:
$$x=\alpha t, y=\beta t, z=\gamma t$$
that gives the equation of the cylinder with radius $R:$
 $$x^2+y^2+z^2-R^2= \frac{(\alpha x+\beta y+ \gamma z)^2}{\alpha ^2 +\beta ^2 + \gamma ^2}.$$
To try and use this, I´ve changed the coordinates in such way that the center of the sphere is the origin, which means that the axis of the cylinder will be of the wanted form and then I can just substitute values and then substitute my original coordinates, which gives me:
$$(x-1)^2 +(y+2)^2+ (z+1)^2-9= \frac{\left(2(x-1) -(y+2) -2(z+1)\right)^2}{9}$$

Graphing that doesn´t give me the desired cylinder.
In which part of my reasoning did I commit a mistake?

Comment: Check your plot. It should have worked. Could be a software issue: GeoGebra seems to be have trouble plotting the equation, but Mathematica shows the expected cylinder.

Comment: Thank you so much, I wouldn´t have guessed that the error was of geogebra

Comment: Probably worth submitting a bug report if that’s what you were using.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the equation of the sphere is $(x-1)^2 + (y+2)^2 + (z+1)^2 = 9$, which has radius $3$ and centre $(1,-2,-1)$. The axis of the cylinder must pass through the centre, and must have radius $3$, and height $6$. Try translating the sphere such that the centre coincides with the origin, and using a rotation matrix to force the axis to be the $z$-axis; compute the equation which is now fairly straightforward, and rotate back.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is sound. It looks like there’s an issue with whatever software you’re using to plot these surfaces. When I tried to plot your cylinder’s equation in GeoGebra, for instance, it decided that the surface was a hyperboloid of one sheet, but didn’t show anything. However, after rearringing the equation in various ways, I was finally able to get it to plot a cylinder by moving everything to one side of the equation, fully expanding it and eliminating the denominators:

[image]

Mathematica was able to plot the unmodified cylinder equation without any issues.